# Data Modal of primefaces not showing refresh data form backing bean

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces

I am new to primefaces and my english is not that much good. I have generated a datatable and when i click on data table view button a model diloag box will appear with backing bean data. My problem is my diloag is not showing current data from backing bean.but when i refresh the page by going to url it will show my previous data. I am adding mu code here with backing bean please help

My .xhtm is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <ui:composition template="/layouts/BasicTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">

      <div class="container">
      <script type="text/javascript">

      alert('hi');

      </script>

        <h:form prependId="false" id="mainform">

            <p:dataTable var="test" value="#{examinationFormBean.candidateList}" paginator="true" rows="10" id="datatable">

                <p:column headerText="Id">
                    <h:outputText value="#{test.id}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Name Of Candidate">
                    <h:outputText value="#{test.user.name}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Mobile No ">
                    <h:outputText value="#{test.user.mobileNo}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="E-mail Address">
                    <h:outputText value="#{test.user.email}" />
                </p:column>

                 <p:column headerText="View/Action">
                        <p:commandLink value="View"   action="#      {examinationFormBean.readFormStatus(test.id)}"  oncomplete="PF('test').show()">
                        </p:commandLink>
                 </p:column>

             </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>

        </div>



         <p:dialog  widgetVar="test"   id="dialog" height="600" width="760">

            <h:form class="form-horizontal" id="data">
              <div class="row" >
                  <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true" />
                   <p:panel header="Examination Details" id="data">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="4"  border="1"  id="panael1" style="text-align: left;color: #333399;" width="760">

                            <h:outputText   value="#{msg['elicense.examinationform.personal.proposeofexam']}"/>
                            <h:outputText id="propExam" value="#{examinationFormBean.examination.name}"/>

                            <h:outputText  value="#{msg['elicense.examinationform.personal.classofcertificates']}" />
                            <c:if test="#{examinationFormBean.elementaryPrinciples==true}">
                                   Elemetry Principle
                             </c:if>

                            <!-- <h:outputText id="grid"  value="Elemetry Principle" rendered="#{examinationFormBean.elementaryPrinciples==true}"/>  -->

                            <c:if test="#{examinationFormBean.wiringForSystem==true}">

                             <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                             <h:outputText id="data1" value="Wiring for System not Exceeding 250 Volts"/>

                            </c:if>


                            <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                            <h:outputText id="data2" value="D. C. Apparatus not Exceeding 650 Volts" rendered="#{examinationFormBean.dcApparatus==true}"/>

                            <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                            <h:outputText id="data3" value="A. C. Apparatus not Exceeding 650 Volts" rendered="#{examinationFormBean.acApparatus==true}"  />

                            <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                            <h:outputText id="data4" value="Underground Cables Voltage upto 1100 Volts" rendered="#{examinationFormBean.undergroundCable1100Volts==true}"/> 

                            <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                            <h:outputText id="data5" value="Underground Cables Voltage upto 11900 Volts" rendered="#{examinationFormBean.undergroundCable11900Volts==true}"/>

                            <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                            <h:outputText id="data6" value="Underground Cables Voltage exceeding 33000 Volts" rendered="#{examinationFormBean.undergroundCable3300Volts==true}"/>   

                            <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                            <h:outputText id="data7" value="Installation exceeding 650 Votts" rendered="#{examinationFormBean.installationExceding650Volts==true}"/>

                            <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                            <h:outputText id="data8" value="Overhead lies Upto 650 Volts" rendered="#{examinationFormBean.overHeadLiesupto650Volts==true}"/>

                            <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                            <h:outputText id="data9" value="Overhead lies Upto 33000 Volts" rendered="#{examinationFormBean.overHeadLiesupto3300Volts==true}"/>     

                            <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                            <h:outputText id="data10" value="Overhead lies Exceeding 33000 Volts" rendered="#{examinationFormBean.overHeadLiesExceeding3300Volts==true}"/>  

                             <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                           <h:outputText id="data11" value="Mining Installation(Bellow Ground)" rendered="#{examinationFormBean.minigInstallation==true}"/>

                            <p:spacer></p:spacer>    
                            <h:outputText id="data12" value="Mining Installation(Bellow Ground)" rendered="#{examinationFormBean.minigInstallation==true}"/>    

                             <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                            <h:outputText id="data13" value="Wiring for System not exceeding 650 Volts" rendered="#{examinationFormBean.wiringForSystemUpto650Volts==true}"/>

                            <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                            <h:outputText id="data14" value="Electric Lt" rendered="#{examinationFormBean.electricIt==true}"/>

                            <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                            <h:outputText id="data15" value="Electrict Signs" rendered="#{examinationFormBean.electricSigns==true}"/>

                             <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                            <h:outputText id="data16" value="Medium Pressure Indian Electricity Rules 1959" rendered="#{examinationFormBean.mediumPressure==true}"/>

                             <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                            <h:outputText id="data17" value="Motor wiring(Including Generators)" rendered="#{examinationFormBean.motorWiring==true}"/>

                             <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                            <h:outputText id="data18" value="Overhead Lines(LT)" rendered="#{examinationFormBean.ltOverHeadLines==true}"/>

                             <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                            <h:outputText id="data19" value="Pepar Insulated cables(laying and joining)" rendered="#{examinationFormBean.paperInsulatedCables==true}"/>

                            <h:outputText value="#{msg['elicense.examinationform.examination.centerofexamination']}" />
                            <h:outputText id="examcenterid" value="#{examinationFormBean.center.name}" />

                            <h:outputText value="#{msg['elicense.examinationform.examination.languagepaper']}" />
                            <h:outputText id="language" value="#{examinationFormBean.language.name}" />

                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>



                    <!-- personal details -->

                        <ui:include src="/pages/personalView.xhtml" />



                    <!-- Education Qualification -->

                    <p:panel header="Education Qualification">

                        <ui:include src="/pages/educationalQualificationsView.xhtml" />


                    </p:panel>


                    <!-- Certificate or Permit Details -->


                    <p:panel header="Previous Certificate Details">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="text-align: left;color: #333399;"  width="760">

                            <h:outputText   value="#{msg['elicense.examinationform.academic.premitno']}" />
                            <h:outputText id="permitid" value="#{examinationFormBean.previousCertificate.previousPermitNo}" />

                            <h:outputText   value="#{msg['elicense.examinationform.academic.certificate']}" />
                            <h:outputText id="certificateid"    value="#{examinationFormBean.previousCertificateNo}" />

                            <h:outputText   value="#{msg['elicense.examinationform.academic.otherstatepermitno']}" />
                            <h:outputText id="otherstatepermitid"   value="#{examinationFormBean.otherStatePermitNo}" />

                            <h:outputText   value="#{msg['elicense.examinationform.academic.otherstatecertificateno']}" />
                            <h:outputText id="otherstatecertificateid"  value="#{examinationFormBean.otherStateCertificateNo}" />

                            <!-- <h:outputText
                                value="#{msg['elicense.examinationform.academic.dateofissue']}" />
                            <h:outputText id="compopupforprivious"
                                value="#{examinationFormBean.previousRegistrationDate}" />
                 -->
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>


                    <!-- Experience Details -->

                    <p:panel header="Experience Details">
                        <ui:include src="/pages/experienceView.xhtml" />
                    </p:panel>



                    <!-- Treasury Challan Details -->

                    <ui:include src="/pages/treasuryChallanView.xhtml" />


                    <!-- Attachment -->

                    <p:panel header="Upload necessary Document">

                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="text-align: left;color: #333399;" width="760" border="1">

                            <h:outputText value="#{msg['elicense.examinationform.uplod.document']}" />

                            <p:graphicImage value="#{examinationFormBean.candidatePhoto}" />

                            <h:outputText  value="#{msg['elicense.examinationform.uplod.sign']}" />
                            <p:graphicImage value="#{examinationFormBean.signature}"    mode="simple" disabled="false" label="Candidates Signature " />
                            <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                             <p:messages id="messageid"/>





                        <h:outputText value="Action :" class="alignment"/>

                         <p:selectOneRadio id="console" value="#{examinationFormBean.action}" required="true" label="Action">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Accept" itemValue="CD3" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Reject" itemValue="CD4" />
                         </p:selectOneRadio>

                        <!-- <h:outputLabel value="Comment:"></h:outputLabel>
                        <h:inputText id="compid"    value="#{examinationFormBean.comment}" /> -->
                         <p:spacer></p:spacer>

                          <p:commandButton value="Proceed to Zonal Electrical Inspector>>"
                              action="#{examinationFormBean.saveFormStatus()}"  update="@this,messageid,data"   process="data"  oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) PF('test').hide()" >

                              <f:ajax  update="datatable"/>
                          </p:commandButton>

                        </h:panelGrid>

                    </p:panel>

                </div>
        </h:form>   

    </p:dialog>



    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

and my backing bean is :

```
package brahmaputra.bohniman.elicense.core.managedbeans;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.primefaces.event.FlowEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

import brahmaputra.bohniman.elicense.core.models.Center;
import brahmaputra.bohniman.elicense.core.models.CertificateClass;
import brahmaputra.bohniman.elicense.core.models.Education;
import brahmaputra.bohniman.elicense.core.models.Examination;
import brahmaputra.bohniman.elicense.core.models.ExaminationDetails;
import brahmaputra.bohniman.elicense.core.models.Experience;
import brahmaputra.bohniman.elicense.core.models.FormStatus;
import brahmaputra.bohniman.elicense.core.models.Language;
import brahmaputra.bohniman.elicense.core.models.PersonalDetails;
import brahmaputra.bohniman.elicense.core.models.PreviousCertificate;
import brahmaputra.bohniman.elicense.core.models.TreasuryChallan;
import brahmaputra.bohniman.elicense.core.models.User;
import brahmaputra.bohniman.elicense.core.models.Wizard;
import brahmaputra.bohniman.elicense.core.services.DDUtilService;
import brahmaputra.bohniman.elicense.core.services.ExaminationDetailsService;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped


public class ExaminationFormBean{


//To Read Form Staus
public void readFormStatus(Long id)
{

    System.out.println("id is "+id);


    //To display formstatus
     formStatus  = examinationDetailsService.readFormStatusIdById(id);

    //To display examination details
    ExaminationDetails examinationDetails=examinationDetailsService.readExaminationDetails(id);


    setExamination(examinationDetails.getExamination());
    setCenter(examinationDetails.getCenter());
    setLanguage(examinationDetails.getLanguage());
    setAcApparatus(examinationDetails.getAcApparatus());
    setDcApparatus(examinationDetails.getDcApparatus());
    setElectricIt(examinationDetails.getElectricIt());
    setElectricSigns(examinationDetails.getElectricSigns());
    setElementaryPrinciples(examinationDetails.getElementaryPrinciples());
    setHighPressure(examinationDetails.getHighPressure());
    setHtOverHeadLines(examinationDetails.getHtOverHeadLines());
    setInstallationExceding650Volts(examinationDetails.getInstallationExceding650Volts());
    setLtOverHeadLines(examinationDetails.getLtOverHeadLines());
    setMediumPressure(examinationDetails.getMediumPressure());
    setMotorWiring(examinationDetails.getMotorWiring());
    setMinigInstallation(examinationDetails.getMinigInstallation());
    setOtherInstallation(examinationDetails.getOtherInstallation());
    setOverHeadLiesExceeding3300Volts(examinationDetails.getOverHeadLiesExceeding3300Volts());
    setOverHeadLiesupto3300Volts(examinationDetails.getOverHeadLiesupto3300Volts());
    setOverHeadLiesupto650Volts(examinationDetails.getOverHeadLiesupto3300Volts());
    setPaperInsulatedCables(examinationDetails.getPaperInsulatedCables());
    setWiringForSystem(examinationDetails.getWiringForSystem());
    setWiringForSystemUpto650Volts(examinationDetails.getWiringForSystemUpto650Volts());

    System.out.println("Examination"+examinationDetails.getExamination().getName());




    //To display personal info
    personalDetails=examinationDetailsService.readPersonalDetailsById(id);
    personalBean.setFatherName(personalDetails.getFatherName());
    personalBean.setCitizenshipReason(personalDetails.getCitizenshipReason());
    personalBean.setCitizenshipValue(personalDetails.getOtherReason());
    personalBean.setNationality(personalDetails.getNationality());
    personalBean.setDateofBirth(personalDetails.getDateOfBirth());
    personalBean.setPermanentAddressLine1(personalDetails.getPermanentAddressLine1());
    personalBean.setPermanentAddressLine2(personalDetails.getPermanentAddressLine2());
    personalBean.setPermanentDistrict(personalDetails.getPermanentDistrict());
    personalBean.setPermanentPinCode(personalDetails.getPermanentPincode());
    personalBean.setPermanentState(personalDetails.getPermanentState());
    personalBean.setPresentAddressLine1(personalDetails.getPresentAddressLine1());
    personalBean.setPresentAddressLine2(personalDetails.getPermanentAddressLine2());
    personalBean.setPresentDistrict(personalDetails.getPresentDistrict());
    personalBean.setPresentState(personalDetails.getPresentState());
    personalBean.setPresentPinCode(personalDetails.getPresentPincode());

    //to display Educational qualification
    Education education=examinationDetailsService.readEducationById(id);
    educationalQualificationsBean.setInstituteName(education.getInstituteName());
    educationalQualificationsBean.setCertificateNumber(education.getCertificateNo());
    educationalQualificationsBean.setDegree(education.getDegree());



    //To display previous certificate display
    previousCertificate=examinationDetailsService.readCertificateById(id);
    this.setPreviousCertificateNo(previousCertificate.getPreviousCertificateNo());
    this.setPreviousPermitNo(previousCertificate.getPreviousPermitNo());
    this.setOtherStateCertificateNo(previousCertificate.getOtherStateCertificateNo());
    this.setOtherStatePermitNo(previousCertificate.getOtherStatePermitNo());

    //To display experiance details
    Experience experience=examinationDetailsService.readExperianceById(id);
    experienceBean.setCommenceDateOne(experience.getCommenceDateOne());
    experienceBean.setCommenceDateThree(experience.getCommenceDateThree());
    experienceBean.setCommenceDateTwo(experience.getCommenceDateTwo());
    experienceBean.setOrganisationNameOne(experience.getOrganisationNameOne());
    experienceBean.setOrganisationNameThree(experience.getOrganisationNameThree());
    experienceBean.setOrganisationNameTwo(experience.getOrganisationNameTwo());
    experienceBean.setTerminatiDateOne(experience.getTerminatiDateOne());
    experienceBean.setTerminatiDateThree(experience.getTerminatiDateThree());
    experienceBean.setTerminationDateTwo(experience.getTerminationDateTwo());

    //To disply treasury challan details
    TreasuryChallan treasuryChallan =new TreasuryChallan();
    treasuryChallan=examinationDetailsService.readTreasuryChallanById(id);
    treasuryChallanBean.settChallanAmount(treasuryChallan.getAmount());
    treasuryChallanBean.settChallanBank(treasuryChallan.getBankName());
    treasuryChallanBean.settChallanBankBranch(treasuryChallan.getBranchName());
    treasuryChallanBean.settChallanDate(treasuryChallan.getDate());
    treasuryChallanBean.settChallanName(treasuryChallan.getTreasuryName());
    treasuryChallanBean.settChallanNo(treasuryChallan.getChallanNo());



}


//To save application status
public String saveFormStatus()
{
    System.out.println("hiiii"+this.getComment());

    formStatus.setStatus(getAction());
    examinationDetailsService.saveFormStatus(formStatus);

    /* FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Car Selected", "Id:");

     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);*/

    System.out.println("Hi page successfully save"+getAction());
    this.setAction("");


    //resetForm();
    return  "/pages/AdminView.xhtml";

}






// To Reset the Form
public String resetForm()
{

    personalBean.setApplicantName(null);
    personalBean.setCitizenshipReason(null);
    personalBean.setCitizenshipValue(null);
    personalBean.setDateofBirth(null);
    personalBean.setFatherName(null);
    personalBean.setNationality(null);
    personalBean.setPermanentAddressLine1(null);
    personalBean.setPermanentAddressLine2(null);
    personalBean.setPermanentDistrict(null);
    personalBean.setPermanentPinCode(null);
    personalBean.setPermanentState(null);
    personalBean.setPresentAddressLine1(null);
    personalBean.setPresentAddressLine2(null);
    personalBean.setPresentDistrict(null);
    personalBean.setPresentState(null);
    personalBean.setPresentPinCode(null);
    personalBean.setCopyAddress(false);

    educationalQualificationsBean.setDegreeCertificateNumber(null);
    educationalQualificationsBean.setDegreeSchoolName(null);
    educationalQualificationsBean.setHsCertificateNumber(null);
    educationalQualificationsBean.setHslcCertificateNumber(null);
    educationalQualificationsBean.setHslcSchoolName(null);
    educationalQualificationsBean.setHsSchoolName(null);
    educationalQualificationsBean.setPgCertificateNumber(null);
    educationalQualificationsBean.setPgInstituteName(null);
    educationalQualificationsBean.setTechnical(null);
    educationalQualificationsBean.setTechnicalCertificateNumber(null);

    experienceBean.setCommenceDateOne(null);
    experienceBean.setCommenceDateThree(null);
    experienceBean.setCommenceDateTwo(null);
    experienceBean.setOrganisationNameOne(null);
    experienceBean.setOrganisationNameThree(null);
    experienceBean.setOrganisationNameTwo(null);
    experienceBean.setTerminatiDateOne(null);
    experienceBean.setTerminatiDateThree(null);
    experienceBean.setTerminationDateTwo(null);

    treasuryChallanBean.settChallanAmount(null);
    treasuryChallanBean.settChallanBank(null);
    treasuryChallanBean.settChallanBankBranch(null);
    treasuryChallanBean.settChallanDate(null);
    treasuryChallanBean.settChallanName(null);
    treasuryChallanBean.settChallanNo(null);
    treasuryChallanBean.settChallanPaid(null);

    examination=null;
    center=null;
    language=null;
    previousCertificate=null;
    previousPermitNo=null;
    previousCertificateNo=null;
    otherStatePermitNo=null;
    otherStateCertificateNo=null;
    previousRegistrationDate=null;
    elementaryPrinciples = false;
    wiringForSystem = false;
    dcApparatus = false;
    acApparatus = false;
    undergroundCable1100Volts = false;
    undergroundCable11900Volts = false;
    undergroundCable3300Volts = false;
    installationExceding650Volts = false;
    overHeadLiesupto650Volts = false;
    overHeadLiesupto3300Volts = false;
    overHeadLiesExceeding3300Volts = false;
    minigInstallation = false;
    wiringForSystemUpto650Volts = false;
    electricIt = false;
    electricSigns = false;
    mediumPressure = false;
    motorWiring = false;
    ltOverHeadLines = false;
    paperInsulatedCables = false;
    highPressure = false;
    htOverHeadLines = false;
    otherInstallation = false;
    examinationPart.clear();

    return  "/pages/examinationForm.xhtml";


}




}
```

Am adding the code which is responsible for my dilog box .I am new to stackoverflow so i am not amble to place my code. My bean is in session scope and the method read readFormStatus(id) getting data from database and am setting data on my backing bean.

Please help , Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add

```
update=":data"
```

on the button that shows the dialog.

You refresh the data on the bean, but you never tell the dialog to update with these refreshed data.

Comment: Its giving me the error Cannot find component with expression ":form-horizontal:data" referenced from "j_idt12:datatable:0:j_idt33".

Comment: giving me the same error Cannot find component with expression ":data" referenced from "j_idt12:datatable:0:j_idt33".

Comment: You can view the resulting html in browser and search for ":data". Maybe you have a component in the template around this content, the id of this component will be prepended before ":data". Just copy whatever you find to the update on the button, but if the id is autogenerated it would be better to give it a manual id

Comment: if i give update=":data" page is not generating and showing error

Answer (score 0):

The "update" attribute on the `<p:commandLink>` will indeed make it.
But I think that if you want to update the content of the following form

```
<h:form class="form-horizontal" id="data">
```

you'll actually have to update the dialog

```
<p:dialog  widgetVar="test"   id="dialog" height="600" width="760">
```

So basically, your commandLink should be like this

```
<p:commandLink value="View" update=":dialog" action="#examinationFormBean.readFormStatus(test.id)}"  oncomplete="PF('test').show()">
```

Comment: but if a put update=":diloag" its showing that component is not found

Comment: How is the <ui:define name="content"> integrated in the template? Is there a form, panel, ... in the template?

Comment: There is panel available in template

Comment: Then try building the update attribute value like ":{panelId}:dialog"